# update MSBUILD to 17.6 that comes with the may 2023 update of .NET 7.0.302 SDK breaks build

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, blazor

since the eveining of 16/5/2023 our builds of a blazor solution are failing. This happend because a new .NET version was released. This version 7.0.302 brings a new MSBuild version 17.6 and causes builds to fail

see versioning info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/versioning-sdk-msbuild-vs

upgraded to same SDK on local machine, and indeed same problemen start to occure

> The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute
> 'bind-Model'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or
> 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like
> 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary workaround, you can fix your SDK in global.json in solution root

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.203",
    "rollForward": "disable",
    "allowPrerelease": false
  }
}
```

documentation found on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

also keep in mind when you fixed set this, and you have docker builds, also specify a fixed SDK in your docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.203 AS build
WORKDIR /src
```